# Using ffmpeg, is it possible to convert a blu-ray folder to a MKV file and add chapter titles in one go?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, matroska

From time to time, I have to convert the files which are referenced by a playlist from a blu-ray disc to a MKV file. I normally use `ffmpeg` under Windows in a command line like the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -analyzeduration 1G -probesize 1G -fix_sub_duration -playlist 00001 -i "bluray:D:\Daten\Temp\My Blu-Ray Disc" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -codec copy c:\Users\User\Desktop\result.mkv
```

That works so far.

However, I am looking for a way to add chapter titles (metadata) to the resulting MKV file **directly along with the initial conversion in one go**.

I am aware that I can add chapter titles to the MKV file **after** it has been created. However, that means copying (i.e. demuxing and remuxing) it again. Since the files sometimes are about 40 GB, this causes a non-negligible wear for the disks.

Therefore I'd like to know how to change the command line so that the chapter title metadata is inserted into the MKV file in one go during the first conversion. I have tried the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -analyzeduration 1G -probesize 1G -fix_sub_duration -playlist 00001 -i "bluray:D:\Daten\Temp\My Blu-Ray Disc" -i metadata.txt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map_metadata 1 -codec copy c:\Users\User\Desktop\result.mkv
```

with `metadata.txt` being something like that:

```
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=9999
title=Chapter Title 1

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=10000
END=19999
title=Chapter Title 2
```

That did not produce an error message, but the resulting MKV file did not contain the chapter metadata. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can add chapters with mkvtoolnix without remuxing AFAIK, although if you want to add it from a file (with `mkvpropedit`), it probably doesn't take one of type like you pasted above.

Comment: I am currently doing it with `mkvtoolnix` (using the correct input file format), but unfortunately, it demuxes and remuxes the file, which is why I asked. However, I didn't know `mkvpropedit` yet, so thank you very much for the hint. I'll see whether it helps me solve the problem and report back.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I didn't find `mkvpropedit` on my system, although I have installed `mkvtoolnix` and AFAIK `mkvpropedit` should be part of it. However, motivated by your comment, I explored `mkvtoolnixGUI` a bit further and saw that it can do exactly what I want. Therefore: Question actually not answered, but problem solved. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it - you have put me on the right track.

Comment: Instead of first only pulling the audio and video stream off the disk, I would suggest using MakeMkv. This tool pulls the movie along with metadata, chapters and subtitles directly from the BluRay disk, and writes it to a .mkv file which can then be further processed e.g. using ffmpeg or DonMelton's other_video_transcoding toolset.

Comment: @DarkDiamond Thanks for the hint, and +1. I'll try that and look whether MakeMkv allows to edit the chapter titles.